# move uploaded file to different user home folder as root in php

Tags: php, linux, permissions, centos6

I'm creating a php proxy upload script to handle incoming file uploads from a desktop app.

File uploads are secured and only permitted people can send files but they all have a different user on a CentOS server thus each with a different home directory

This php upload proxy is on it own home directory

How can this file move the uploaded tmp file to a different home directory than its own?

I tried with full hope to chown the php file to root, but this doesn't work. Php isn't even executed when the file is requested.

how to permit this script to upload files wherever it wants?
I obviously don't want to chmod 777 the (predefined) target directories

Comment: Is the PHP running under Apache?

Comment: Yes (server is running WHM)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's running under Apache, the **INSECURE** option is to allow the process itself (not the file) to run as root. Just to make doubly sure, this is a **BAD** option.

The better option is to create a directory in each user's home that allows write only access to PHP. No read, no execute, just a blind drop box. You can achieve this with ACL's or with permissions.

Comment: You could add all your users and the php process user (defaults to www-data) to a common group, then chgrp the users home folder to the new group and finally chmod 0770 the directory.

Comment: If I understand this right, All users (with your called dropbox) will be able to drop files in each others dropbox. Isn't it possible to only allow this to the owner and 1 external user?

Comment: Actually, don't use `0770`, use `0720`. That give the owner full rights, group write only and all nuttin'. Also don't set these on the home folder, set them on a specific folder within. Never allow PHP to see everything or execute!

Comment: Another option is to add the www-data user to the users main group and chmod the directory to ```0720``` as suggested by Kevin. This way the other users may not write to others home directory.

Comment: @VincentDuprez to keep it locked so that the relationship isn't between all users including PHP, have a google for ACL's (Access Control Lists). This'll allow you more fine-grained control over the permissions and you can then allow WRITE-ONLY access to just the `www-data` user (or whatever PHP is running as).